# NIC flashing link-link-link and then dies, then repeats

Tags: motherboard, network-adapter

I've got several wall ports that all run down to the same switch - tested them all with ethernet cable checker to make sure the drops were ok and turned out all good.

1. I can plug in a variety of systems and networking works fine. (Link light on, and then it starts blinking data light)
2. But one set of motherboards (Asus X299-A II), their onboard NIC flashes link-link-link (and data light is on) a few times and then lights shut off and then repeats. Of course system never starts communicating.
3. If I plug in this troubled NIC (Asus X299-A II) to a switch and plug the switch into the port, links up, starts flashing data, networking is fine.

This troubled system is a Windows system, motherboard: ASUS PRIME X299-A II

Other brand of motherboard, NIC was successful and communicating without switch, plugged right into the ports: X299 UD4 Pro-CF

Has anyone seen this behavior before?

Comment: what are you plugging it into when it fails, if not a switch or switch like device? are you trying to directly connect two PCs?

Comment: @FrankThomas Hi Frank, the port has ethernet that runs down to a large switch

Comment: is it possible that the in-wall cable or the patch connecting the PC to the wall is a crossover cable? modern nic's and switches should implement MDI-X so they can dynamically change their pinouts, but that would not work  work for the wall jack, so if the cable in the wall and the cable connecting the PC to the wall are not of the same type, that would explain the issue.

Comment: @FrankThomas Theres no chance at all, since other systems work on it. It seems like the NICs on the specific  motherboard have some particularity thats causing it... otherwise other systems wouldnt work on it

Comment: have you set the linkspeed/duplex on either side of the connection? if you set a setting on either end, be sure to set it on both, or leave both set as Auto-negotiating. do you have the chipset drivers for the system installed?

Comment: Intel® I219V on Asus X299-A II is 1000Base-T only. Probably other boards connects on 100Mb. Check if your switch/cable/pinout is gigabit compatible.

Comment: @mooh-pooh Thanks. When I plug it into a switch tho, and boots to Windows it delivers 750Mbps sustained from a resource so I know thats ok. I've tried installing the Asus Gb LAN driver that Frank Thomas mentioned. I may delete if that turns out to solve the case. Thanks all!